# Android: How to scroll a closed path

Tags: android, android-canvas

There's an arbitrary **closed path**, what I'm going to do is implement a "drawing animation" based on `PathMeasure.getSegment(0, pathMeasure.length * animationProgress, path)`. It's like drawing with a pen on a piece of paper.

However, I want to change the starting point. Since the path is closed, theoretically, you can draw the full graph no matter where you start. How to do that?

For example:

[image: scroll example]